# Relationships between custom taxonomies in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I’m interested in defining relationships between custom taxonomies but I’ve been unable to find much in the way of documentation on this topic. Perhaps this can be done using the Pods framework (?), but I'm not sure. What I’d like to be achieved is the following:

1. There’s the ‘found_object’ custom post type.
2. There’s the ‘materials’ custom taxonomy for terms like plastic, wood, glass, etc. attached to the ‘found_object’ post type.
3. There’s also the ‘physical_properties’ custom taxonomy for, say, electrical conductivity and other properties that a given material is known to possess.
4. I would like to assign the above properties to my materials so that the physical_properties taxonomy terms for each of the found_objects get auto-populated once the materials of an object are selected. Or to reiterate: if an object has one or more materials assigned to it manually this will automatically assign all the properties of these materials to the object and different materials should obviously be allowed to share the same properties.

I need this to let the user arrive at these objects by filtering them by physical properties directly (not by materials per se) using the FacetWP plugin.

I vaguely understand that this can hopefully be done using the Pods plugin by setting up a relationship between my taxonomies by creating a relationship field. But other than that I don’t quite understand what to do.

I would greatly appreciate your help or suggestions.
Kind regards, Svetlana.

Comment: You could use term_meta (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_term_meta) to store the physical properties of the materials. Then you should be able to use the default wordpress query to query found_object's having any terms having a specified  property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by using the Pods framework in tandem with the FacetWP plugin (by taking advantage of one of its indexer hooks) as is demonstrated [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/relationships-between-custom-taxonomies/#post-11315138) (with the link to the relevant code snippet included).